# How to query nested path with spaces and other characters

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

I have a rather 'complex' elasticsearch document that has spaces present in the path. Is there any way in which to get the query working without a reindex? :)

```
"_source": {
    "threads": {
        "MANAGEMENT DISCUSSION SECTION": [],
        "Q&A": [
            {
                "sentence_sentiment": [
                       {
                           "sentiment": {...}

}
],...
```

My current code looks something like this.

```
def query_nested(path='threads.Q&A', to_match=None, *args, **kwargs):
    q_match = None
    if to_match:
        for match in to_match:
             if q_match is None:
                 q_match = Q("match", **match)
             else:
                 q_match &= Q("match", **match)

        q = Q("nested", path=path,
              query=q_match,
              inner_hits={})

        s = Search()[kwargs.get('start', 0):kwargs.get('end', 25)]
        s = s.query(q)
        s = s.source(include=["title"])
        s = s.sort('-year', '-month', '-day')

        return s.execute()

    return None
```

But this results in an incorrect query due to the .Q&A of course.

I also tried with threads["Q&A"] but that doesn't work either.

Ideally, I don't want to reindex since the collection is really quite large.

Comment: How about `threads__Q&A`? (double underscore)

Comment: Same problem :(